# Attribute definition order not preserved even in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.6

According to [Python 3.6 release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html), "the class attribute definition order is [now preserved](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep520)". This is described in more detail in [PEP 520](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0520/).

However, I can't seem to get this to work?

For example:

```
class Foo:
    c = 1
    b = 2
    a = 3

print(Foo.__dict__)
# mappingproxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>,
#               '__doc__': None,
#               '__module__': '__main__',
#               '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>,
#               'a': 3,
#               'b': 2,
#               'c': 1})
```

or:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, c=1, b=2, a=3):
        self.c = c
        self.b = b
        self.a = a

foo = Foo()

foo.__dict__
# {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
```

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're running that on 3.6? I tried it and it got all six permutations right: https://repl.it/repls/RepentantPlayfulArchitect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the looks of that output, that's probably not the code you really ran. You probably wrote

```
Foo.__dict__
```

in an IPython interactive session. IPython automatically sorts the keys of dicts and mappingproxy objects when displaying them. (This was eventually [changed](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/whatsnew/version5.html#ipython-5-6) in IPython 5.6 so IPython no longer sorts dict keys on Python 3.6+.)